# How do I add Constructor in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I've just started using create-react-app and am not very familiar with the src setup. I noticed that in App.js, the exported App component is a function, as opposed to class App extends React.Component...

I can't seem to add a constructor to it. Anyone know where I can do so? Thank you

Comment: functional components do not have a `constructor`, only class based components can have a `constructor` defined in them.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the function to a class as:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: 'App.js'
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          {this.state.text}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `useEffect` within the function.

Like:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    // Whatever you like
    console.log("Called in starting of function");
  }, []);
```

Comment: unlike a constructor, `useEffect` hook written like this will run after every render cycle. This hook cannot be used as a `constructor`.

Comment: But the solution is to provide an alternate path which can be similar to constructor. @Yousaf  In functional components this can be closest solution similar to constructor in classes.

Comment: No, it cannot be used as a constructor. It will run after every render cycle which is not like or similar to constructor at all.

Comment: @Yousaf You can use the `useEffect` hook as a constructor but you have to pass the second param as an empty array `[]` then it will only be run once when the component mounts. Ex: `useEffect(() = alert('once'), [])`

Comment: @Pablo not correct. When you pass empty array as second argument in `useEffect` hook, you emulate `componentDidMount` lifecycle method, not a `constructor`. Constructor executes before component is rendered whereas `componentDidMount` executes after component has been rendered. You cannot use `useEffect` component as a constructor and you don't need to inside a functional component

Answer (score 0):

CRA team updated the setup to new React hooks. You are talking about  old react setup. 
You can convert it

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
```

To

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  render() {
```

But i will suggest you to learn react hooks to keep your skills updated.

Answer (score 0):

As App is a functional component it doesn't have the component lifecycle. Therefore you can't specify a constructor.

But with class Based Component you can use the constructor

```
class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

 }

 render(){
 return(
 // code
 //code
 )}
}
```